# How to get rid of new line characters in an output of Node.js util.inspect?

Tags: node.js, output, newline, console.log

An issue with Node.js' [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) function. I use it to colorize Node.js console output and to format objects. All works fine except that `util.inspect` prints all those `\r\n` characters too.

The example. Given a file:

```
// foo.js

console.log("css:\n", util.inspect(css, { depth: 5, colors: true }), '\n');
```

The output:

[image]

How to make `util.inspect` not to print all those `\r\n` characters?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the solution [suggested in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_customizing_util_inspect_colors) is to manually remove the new line characters:

```
util.inspect(css, { depth: 5, colors: true }).replace(/\r?\n/g, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [current documentation of util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), all you need to do is to set `breakLength` to `Infinity` and `compact` to `true`.

In your case that would be

```
console.log("css:\n", util.inspect(css, {
  depth: 5,
  colors: true,
  breakLength: Infinity,
  compact: true,
}), '\n');
```